# SQL: How to sort / order query result in somewhat arbitrary manner?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

I need to sort the results of a query in an UNCONVENTIONAL order.

Say, I do a search for "Chair". I want all the records STARTING with Chair to be listed first alphabetically, then other records that CONTAIN "chair" to be listed afterwards in alphabetical order. So "Blue Chair" would be listed after "Chair Blue" for example.

Please note the STARTING and CONTAINING conditions.
How should I implement this sort? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look?

```
SELECT *, 1 as sort_pref FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'CHAIR%'
UNION
SELECT *, 2 as sort_pref FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%CHAIR%' AND column NOT LIKE 'CHAIR%'
ORDER BY sort_pref, column
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an ORDER BY with a function (your own, or PATINDEX as below), for example:

```
create table test (value varchar(255))
delete from test
insert into test values ('Foo')
insert into test values ('Bar')
insert into test values ('BlueChair')
insert into test values ('Chair')
insert into test values ('NotABlueChair')
insert into test values ('chairs')
insert into test values ('Zoo')

select * from test where value like '%chair%' order by PATINDEX('%chair%', value)
```

**Returns:**

```
Chair
chairs
BlueChair
NotABlueChair
```

Answer (score 3):

**(Turns out this is MySQL-specific)**

The shortest I can come up with in SQL is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%chair%'
ORDER BY IF(column LIKE 'chair%', 0, 1), column;
```

The IF gives the rows which start with 'chair' a 0 and the ones that don't a 1. The sorting order in SQL sorts the rows according to the first "column" specified first, then within that sorting order it will sort it according to the second, and so on.

To clarify, this is what it will look like for the ORDER BY:

```
ChairBlack  = 0, 'ChairBlack'
BlackChair  = 1, 'BlackChair'
Hello Chair = 1, 'Hello Chair'
Chair       = 0, 'Chair'
```

Making it sort it like this:

```
Chair       = 0, 'Chair'
ChairBlack  = 0, 'ChairBlack'
BlackChair  = 1, 'BlackChair'
Hello Chair = 1, 'Hello Chair'
```

Comment: Could you explain what the 0 and 1 mean in the IF expression? I am new to SQL. Thanks.

Comment: The IF() in SQL takes three arguments. First argument is what is evaluated if it is true or false, second argument is what is returned if the expression is true and the third argument is what is returned if the expression is false. So, it gives the columns which start with 'chair' a 0 and the ones that don't a 1 sorting all the ones that start with chair before the ones that dont. :)

Comment: Your code looks absolutely elegant but I keep on getting error near IF. Must be because I am using Microsoft SQL which might not support this IF expression. I've been looking things up but if (no pun intended) you can give me a pointer, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @mikn: which "dialect" or vendor implementation of SQL has `IF()` ?? I know T-SQL (Sybase, SQL Server) doesn't....

Comment: The IF() function might be MySQL specific, actually. You could try making it `(CASE WHEN (column LIKE 'chair%') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` which should be possible to do in T-SQL. But I'm not 100% if you can evaluate expressions at that point in the query... Apparently the next version of MSSQL will have an IIF which will be the same as MySQLs IF(): [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)