# sql - group/order same column DESC and with random values

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: How to sort / order query result in somewhat arbitrary manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305920/sql-how-to-sort-order-query-result-in-somewhat-arbitrary-manner)

I want to order a column like so (DESC values):
 c,b,a. 
However at the very end of the DESC, I want to display values g,h,i (if exist) . Do I need to do a union on the column from a sub-query?

This is the SQL script so far:

```
SELECT cars,size from car_table
GROUP BY cars, size
ORDER BY cars DESC,size ASC
```

Cars is the column I am trying to run my multi-sort on.

Comment: Can u show sample data and expected results.?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT cars,size 
from cars_table
GROUP BY cars, size
ORDER BY CASE WHEN cars in ('g','h','i') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC
, cars DESC
, size ASC
```

Here is a fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d26a8/1/0

Comment: That is a good option, I would change the case statement to `cars in ('g','h','i')` just because it's more specific to the posters question.

Answer (score 2):

```
select cars, size
from car_table
group by cars, size
order by
  case 
     when cars in ('a', 'b', 'c') then cars
     else '1'
  end desc,
  case 
     when cars in ('g', 'h', 'i') then cars
     else '1'
  end
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ddc2/2)

**Output:**

```
| CARS | SIZE |
---------------
|    c |    1 |
|    b |    1 |
|    a |    1 |
|    g |    1 |
|    h |    1 |
|    i |    1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

UNION + Subquery would be my choice.

```
SELECT cars, size 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 OrderNumber, cars, size from car_table
    GROUP BY cars, size
    WHERE cars not in ('g','h','i')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, cars, size from car_table
    GROUP BY cars, size
    WHERE cars in ('g','h','i')
) aSubQuery
ORDER BY OrderNumber ASC, cars DESC, size ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT cars,size
FROM (
   SELECT cars,size, CASE SUBSTRING(cars,1,1) 
            WHEN 'g' THEN '_z' 
            WHEN 'h' THEN '_y'
            WHEN 'i' THEN '_x'
                     ELSE '' END + cars AS order_cars
   FROM   car_table
   GROUP BY cars,size
) A

ORDER BY order_cars DESC,size ASC
```